# Outlook Redemption: Synchronizing Email Folder via EntryIDs

Tags: outlook-redemption

I'm using Outlook Redemption to write an algorithm that will synchronize SQL database w/ the contents of an email folder.

I'd like to track the emails in the database by Outlook EntryID, but the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864762%28v=office.15%29.aspx) on EntryIDs mentions that one Email Item can have multiple EntryIDs. Under what conditions will an Email Item have more than one EntryID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAPI can refer to the same object using multiple entry ids. Exchange uses so called short-term entry ids (returned by the folder contents table) and long term entry ids (returned from the object itself). Short term entry ids can only be used in the session that returned them, hence they should not be persisted and used across MAPI sessions.